# ENVI error class_doit: An error has occurred during processing Error: "LA_LUDC: Singular matrix encountered, STATUS=2." The result may be invalid

Tags: envi

[image]

I do a Maximum Likelihood Classification in ENVI 5.3. But after the process read the ROI, then appear pop up "ENVI error class_doit: An error has occurred during processing Error: "LA_LUDC: Singular matrix encountered, STATUS=2." The result may be invalid."

[image]

what sould i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should process the ROI with raw imagery without clip/subset.